# Is that a common thing to rely 100% on 3rd party UI tool?

Tags: usability

I am a UI developer working for a software company. We are at the initial stage of planning our first online product. Kendo UI is in the list for UI and it's our leader's idea who is a back-end developer.
Although I am not saying everything has to be tailor-made with full customization, my view is that UI/UX planning should not be constrained to the technical implementation.

I am asked to make up a prototype for the better user interaction ideas but if I already know what they are going to implement is 100% default behaviour that Kendo UI offers, what is the point?

All our competitor's online product are very unique that they hardly use any 3rd party tool apart from more standardized libraries like jQuery.

I lost my motivation, already seeing the output that will look alike others.

If I want to make a good career out of UI designer, do you think I should find a place that understands the real value of user experience?

Comment: As the UI developer, does this mean you are actually responsible for the UI design as well in this particular role? Are there other decision makers that you can influence with a solid argument as well?

Comment: @MichaelLai Thanks a lot for your input. We have about 10 back-end developers and 2 UI/UX designers that do both graphic/usability concept as well as the implementation. Before I joined a year ago, there were no UI specific roles here. I am more experienced than the other UI designer but still more of intermediate position.

Comment: So in this case, what is the other UI designer's view about this? If the lead doesn't listen to the input from the UI/UX people, then you just need to hire graphic designers and front-end developers since it is all about implementation anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Part of being a good UI designer is understanding the balance between business, technical and user requirement/constraints. You will find that different organizations adopt different aspects of the user-centric design philosophy, and as much as you are trying to be an advocate for the user, it is no point designing a product that cannot be built (or sold). Therefore, it is in your best interest as a UI designer to be able to come up with research and sound advice based on best practice and your experience (with being biased towards your own design ideals).

I don't think programmers like to reinvent the wheel, so it is not uncommon to see third party UI tools used. Many designers and developers also use javascript or CSS frameworks so the argument should be based on the suitability of the proposed solution. You'll need to work out how to find the right balance in the new world of UX/Agile development environment, but if you can show that you have taken these considerations into account that's what will make you a better UI designer.